# To run python script in apache spark/Storm

Tags: python, hadoop, apache-spark

I am having an algorithm written in python (not hadoop compatible i.e. not mapper.py and reducer.py) and it is running perfectly in local system (not hadoop).  My objective is to run this in hadoop.

Option 1: Hadoop streaming.  But, I need to convert this python script into mapper and reducer.  Any other way?

Option 2: To run this python script through Storm.  But, I am using cloudera which doesn't have Storm.  either I need to install storm in cloudera or need to use Spark.  If I install storm in cloudera.  Is it better option?

Option 3: To run this python script through Spark (Cloudera).  Is it possible.

This algorithm is not for real time processing.  But, we want to process it in hadoop technology.
Please help with other suitable solution.

Comment: maybe you can describe the algorithm?

Answer (score 1):

First and foremost what are you trying to achieve? What does running on Hadoop technology mean to you? If the goal is to work with a lot of data, this is one thing, if it's to parallelize the algorithm, it's another. My guess is you want both.

First thing is: is the algorithm parallelizable? Can it run on multiple pieces of data at the same time and gather them all in the end to make the final answer? Some algorithms are not, especially if they are recursive and require previously computed data to process the next.

In any case, running on Hadoop means running using Hadoop tools, whether it is Spark, Storm or other services that can run on Python, taking advantage of Hadoop means writing your algorithm for it.
if your algorithm is parallelizable, then likely you can easily take the piece that processes one piece of data and adapt it to run with Spark or Storm on huge datasets.

Comment: Hi MrE,  What this algorithm does is, identify the repeated transactions.  Let's say my transaction file has statement description like 'payment to mobile' everymonth.  Then this algorithm will identify those repeated transaction and write it to output file.  This python written to work in local unix system only.  The size of the file is around 25GB.  Python can handle this file size, but still we wish to run this python script in hadoop environment. So, looking for some better solution.

Comment: Then, load the file in HBase, Hive, Spark SQL or Impala on Hadoop, to make it into a database. Then finding repeat transactions is pretty trivial in SQL.
25Gb is a decent size but is not that huge for a database: it would easily fit on a single node, so you might as well start with a standard database type like MySQL, unless you expect your DB to grow to much bigger size (several TBs) when you will really need Hadoop.

Comment: Hi MrE,  I agree that for this file size we may not required hadoop.  But, existing python algorithm providing solution on identifying repeated transaction.  so, need your help on how to implement this python script in hadoop environment.  We would like to present solution with and without hadoop.  So, as mentioned in my initial question, what would be the best solution to run this python script in hadoop environment.  Hadoop streaming/Storm or Spark or anyother?

Comment: I would then simply load the file on HDFS, use Spark to load into a RDD with pyspark and parse the file as need calling the function on the transaction.

Witout knowing how the algorithm works, it is difficult to elaborate about how to do it. 
If you just want the large file handing capability of hadoop that is what i'd recommend, but likely you won't get much performance improvement if you don't re-write your algorithm for parallel operation.

Comment: Hi MrE,Thank you very much for your time and help!  Will try pyspark.